# opencv не видно кнопок [Закрыто]

Tags: python, opencv

В последних версиях библиотеки opencv-python появились в окне кнопки, но они белые как и фон на котором они размещены, не видно ни текст ни сами кнопки, только если случайно на них навести и прочитать уведомительное окно что это за кнопка. Как изменить фон, чтобы увидеть эти кнопки, и если вообще на них текст, может их еще нужно как-то подписать?

Comment: Вы о чем? Это при вызове `imshow` происходит?

Comment: уже решил, все дело было в `cv2.namedWindow('Name', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` сменил графическое указание и все ок